# rails server - Load Error on start re: bundler runtime

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, runtime, rvm, bundler

I need a good nudge here.  I am having issues with Rails Server.
1st rvm info, then actual error msgs below.  Please help me look at this so I can undo or fix the issues:

here is rvm info:   then followed by error msgs

```
Williams-MacBook-Pro:~ williamfulbright$ rvm info
```

ruby-2.2.3:

```
system:
    uname:       "Darwin Williams-MacBook-Pro.local 15.0.0 Darwin Kernel Version 15.0.0: Sat Sep 19 15:53:46 PDT 2015; root:xnu-3247.10.11~1/RELEASE_X86_64 x86_64"
    system:      "osx/10.11/x86_64"
    bash:        "/bin/bash => GNU bash, version 3.2.57(1)-release (x86_64-apple-darwin15)"
    zsh:         "/bin/zsh => zsh 5.0.8 (x86_64-apple-darwin15.0)"

  rvm:
    version:      "rvm 1.26.11 (latest) by Wayne E. Seguin <wayneeseguin@gmail.com>, Michal Papis <mpapis@gmail.com> [https://rvm.io/]"
    updated:      "21 hours 30 minutes 20 seconds ago"
    path:         "/Users/williamfulbright/.rvm"

  ruby:
    interpreter:  "ruby"
    version:      "2.2.3p173"
    date:         "2015-08-18"
    platform:     "x86_64-darwin14"
    patchlevel:   "2015-08-18 revision 51636"
    full_version: "ruby 2.2.3p173 (2015-08-18 revision 51636) [x86_64-darwin14]"

  homes:
    gem:          "/Users/williamfulbright/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3"
    ruby:         "/Users/williamfulbright/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.3"

  binaries:
    ruby:         "/Users/williamfulbright/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.3/bin/ruby"
    irb:          "/Users/williamfulbright/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.3/bin/irb"
    gem:          "/Users/williamfulbright/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.3/bin/gem"
    rake:         "/Users/williamfulbright/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/bin/rake"

  environment:
    PATH:         "/Users/williamfulbright/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/bin:/Users/williamfulbright/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3@global/bin:/Users/williamfulbright/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.3/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/opt/X11/bin:/Users/williamfulbright/.rvm/bin"
    GEM_HOME:     "/Users/williamfulbright/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3"
    GEM_PATH:     "/Users/williamfulbright/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3:/Users/williamfulbright/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3@global"
    MY_RUBY_HOME: "/Users/williamfulbright/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.3"
    IRBRC:        "/Users/williamfulbright/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.3/.irbrc"
    RUBYOPT:      ""
    gemset:       ""


THE ERRORS:
     such file -- spec (LoadError)
    from /Users/williamfulbright/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/bundler-1.10.6/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:76:in `block (2 levels) in require'
    from /Users/williamfulbright/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/bundler-1.10.6/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:72:in `each'
    from /Users/williamfulbright/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/bundler-1.10.6/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:72:in `block in require'
    from /Users/williamfulbright/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/bundler-1.10.6/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:61:in `each'
    from /Users/williamfulbright/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/bundler-1.10.6/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:61:in `require'
    from /Users/williamfulbright/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/bundler-1.10.6/lib/bundler.rb:134:in `require'
    from /Users/williamfulbright/Ruby/RoR/TwentyOne/config/application.rb:7:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/williamfulbright/Ruby/RoR/TwentyOne/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.4/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:78:in `require'
    from /Users/williamfulbright/Ruby/RoR/TwentyOne/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.4/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:78:in `block in server'
    from /Users/williamfulbright/Ruby/RoR/TwentyOne/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.4/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:75:in `tap'
    from /Users/williamfulbright/Ruby/RoR/TwentyOne/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.4/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:75:in `server'
    from /Users/williamfulbright/Ruby/RoR/TwentyOne/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.4/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:39:in `run_command!'
    from /Users/williamfulbright/Ruby/RoR/TwentyOne/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.4/lib/rails/commands.rb:17:in `<top (required)>'
    from bin/rails:8:in `require'
    from bin/rails:8:in `<main>'
```

Thanks in advance!  I was doing better before trying to get fancy.

Bill

Comment: Can somebody take a look at this problem with the rails server issue I am having.... is it RVM related?

Answer (score 0):

you have loading error at 7th row of `config/application.rb` file (has to be `require "action_mailer/railtie"` or something like that). mistyping, i guess